# change iframe get request to post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, iframe

Currently Im using a iframe which makes a get request. I'd like to change it to a post request. I know iframe allows just a get request. However I'd like to post the response to the same iframe. This is what I did:

```
var frame= $('<iframe/>',{
    id:'test',
});
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataHere,
    success: function(){
        $(document.body).append(frame);
        frame.load(function(){
            elem.remove();
        });
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
   alert('request failed');
   }
});
```

But I get a "405 method not allowed". Any suggestions?